# Retrieving Unique in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm currently using Ruby Version 1.8.7 and  I've been searching around but unable to find a solution for this. I am currently working on creating a unique vendor identifier. But I'll simplify the issue here.

I have a 2D Array for vendors and products:

```
A = [["C"], ["A","D"], ["A","B"], ["B","C","E","F"], ["B","G","K"], [], ["H","I"], [], [], ["I"], ["J"]]
```

What I need to do here is to retrieve the top 5 users (Array index number) with the most number of unique product. In this case.

The top 5 vendors would be:

```
1 - A,D
3 - B,C,E,F
4 - B,G,K
6 - H,I
10 - J
```

#### Example:

Vendor 3 has Products `["B","C","E","F"]` but Vendor 4 has products ["B","G","K"].
Since vendor 4 and 3 both has `["B"]`
Vendor 3 has **3 unique products** `["C","E","F"]`
Vendor 4 has **2 unique products** `["G","K"]`

What I need to return is an Array of Vendors (Based on their index in the 2D Array) of the Top 5 Vendors.

Here are my codes so far:

```
def test

  vendors = [[C], [A,D], [A,B], [B,C,E,F], [B,G,K], [], [H,I], [], [], [I], [J]]
  useridArr = Array(0..vendors.length-1)
  vendors = inplace_quicksort(vendors, 0, vendors.length-1,useridArr)
  getUnique(vendors,useridArr, vendors.length-1)
end

def partition_array(array, left, right, pivot_index, arr)
  pivot_value = array[pivot_index].length
  arr[pivot_index], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[pivot_index]
  array[pivot_index], array[right] = array[right], array[pivot_index]
  store_index = left

  (left..right-1).each do |i|
    if array[i].length < pivot_value
      arr[i], arr[store_index] = arr[store_index], arr[i]
      array[i], array[store_index] = array[store_index], array[i]
      store_index = store_index + 1
    end
  end

  arr[store_index], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[store_index]
  array[store_index], array[right] = array[right], array[store_index]
  return store_index
end

def inplace_quicksort(array, left, right, indexArr)
  if left < right
    pivot_index = (left + ((right - left) / 2)).to_i
    new_pivot_index = partition_array(array, left, right, pivot_index,indexArr)
    inplace_quicksort(array, left, new_pivot_index - 1,indexArr)
    inplace_quicksort(array, new_pivot_index + 1, right,indexArr)
  end
  return array
end

def getUnique(vendors,useridArr, searchFor)
  while searchFor != -1
    p vendors.map {|a| a & vendors[searchFor] }
    searchFor = searchFor - 1 
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough but index 0 `[C]` already exists in index 3. In a sense the vendor in index 3 covers more product that index 0. Hence, the vendor with `[B,C,E,F]` is selected instead. Hopefully this helps. But thanks alot for the prompt response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the `11` elements of `A` corresponds to a vendor and there are (coincidentally) `11` products<sup>1</sup>:

```
A = [[:C], [:A, :D], [:A, :B], [:B, :C, :E, :F], [:B, :G, :K], [],
     [:H, :I], [], [], [:I], [:J]] 

products = A.flatten
  #=> [:C, :A, :D, :A, :B, :B, :C, :E, :F, :B, :G, :K, :H, :I, :I, :J]
products.uniq
  #=> [:C, :A, :D, :B, :E, :F, :G, :K, :H, :I, :J]
products.uniq.size
  #=> 11
```

We begin by computing the number of instances of each product:

```
g = Hash.new(0)
counts = products.each_with_object(g) { |p,h| h[p] += 1 }
  #=> {:C=>2, :A=>2, :D=>1, :B=>3, :E=>1, :F=>1, :G=>1, :K=>1,
  #    :H=>1, :I=>2, :J=>1}
```

`g = Hash.new(0)` creates an empty hash with a default value of zero. That means that if `g` does not have a key `k`, `g[k]` will return zero. Notice the expression `h[p] += 1`. That is called an *abbreviated assignment*. It simply means the expression is expanded to:

```
h[p] = h[p] + 1
```

before it is evaluated. If `h` does not have a key `p`, `h[p]` on the right side returns zero, so `h[p]` is set equal to `0+1 #=> 1`.

Everything above would normally be written more compactly as follows:

```
counts = A.flatten.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |p,h| h[p] += 1 }
```

The products offered by only one vendor are given by:

```
unique_products = counts.select { |_,count| count == 1 }.keys
  #=> [:D, :E, :F, :G, :K, :H, :J]
```

The vendor at offset `3` in `A` has two unique products, `:E` and `:F`:

```
[:B,:C,:E,:F] & unique_products
   #=> [:E, :F]
```

That is:

```
([:B,:C,:E,:F] & unique_products).size
   #=> 2
```

If we want the five vendors with the greatest numbers of unique products, ordered by decreasing numbers of unique products, we can do this:

```
A.sort_by { |a| -(a & unique_products).size }.first(5)
  #=> [[:B, :G, :K], [:B, :C, :E, :F], [:H, :I], [:A, :D], [:J]]
```

In Ruby 2.2+ we can do this more directly, using [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
A.max_by(5) { |a| (a & unique_products).size }
  #=> [[:B, :G, :K], [:B, :C, :E, :F], [:J], [:A, :D], [:H, :I]]
```

The ordering is slightly different, but that's because the last three vendors of the top five all have one unique product.

Wrapping this up, we might write a method as follows:

```
def max_unique_products(products_by_vendor, n)
  counts = products_by_vendor.flatten.
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |p,h| h[p] += 1 }
  unique_products = counts.select { |_,count| count == 1 }.keys
  products_by_vendor.max_by(n) { |a| (a & unique_products).size }
end

max_unique_products(A, 5)
  #=> [[:B, :G, :K], [:B, :C, :E, :F], [:J], [:A, :D], [:H, :I]]
```

**Edit 1:** I forgot you wanted the indices of the top vendors. Just change the last line of the method above to:

```
products_by_vendor.each_with_index.
  max_by(n) { |a,_| (a & unique_products).size }.map(&:last)
```

or:

```
products_by_vendor.each_with_index.
  sort_by { |a,_| -(a & unique_products).size }.first(5).map(&:last)
```

and you will get:

```
max_unique_products(A, 5)
  #=> [4, 3, 10, 1, 6]
```

**Edit 2:** To make this work with Ruby v1.8.7, try this:

```
def max_unique_products(products_by_vendor, n)
  counts = products_by_vendor.flatten.
    reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |h,p| h[p] += 1; h }
  unique_products = counts.select { |_,count| count == 1 }.map(&:first)
  products_by_vendor.each_with_index.
    sort_by { |a,_| -(a & unique_products).size }.first(5).map(&:last)
end
```

It works with v2.2 and I believe that all the methods existed in v1.8.7.

<sup>1. The OP originally defined A as [[C], [A, D]...]. I changed that to [[:C], [:A, :D]...] in my answer. lostcoder then changed it to [["C"], ["A", "D"]...].</sup>

Comment: lost, don't be disheartened by the fact that my code is so much shorter than yours. That happens to everyone who is new to programming or coming to Ruby from a less descriptive language. Think of it as what you have to look forward to as you gain knowledge of Ruby and hone your skills.

Comment: Hi Cary, thanks for the help. I understand the concept and thought process behind your logic and must say it has helped me alot. However, what I need to return are the **Index** of the users who have the most number of unique products. I don't really know how to put this across. But if you refer above, I should return `[1,3,4,6,10]` instead. Also, I am currently using Ruby 1.8.7, where some methods aren't available. Are there any work around for this? Once again, Thanks alot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Egad! 1.8.7!!?? Why? It must be 10 ten years old. I edited the end of my answer to return the indices of the top vendors.

Comment: Hi Cary, my client's requirements are 1.8.7 (no idea why too) but I don't have a choice. Thanks alot for the solution and trying to understand it now! I've implemented the `reduce` but `unique_products = counts.select { |_,count| count == 1 }.keys` gave me a `NoMethodError: undefined method keys`.

Comment: I did an edit to provide a version that should work with Ruby v.1.8.7. See how I used `reduce`. Did you forget to switch the order of the block variables or add `; h` at the end of the block? `Hash#keys` was implemented in v.1.8.7.

Comment: Yup, added the ; h into the `reduce` portion. But I'm still getting the same issue with the `.keys`. method.

Comment: I think I might have found a work around for the `.keys`. Albeit inefficient, but what I did was to convert the hash to an array and `.flatten.each_slice(2).map(&:first)`.  Which removes all the count. I guess this works for now. But thanks alot!! I really appreciate your patience and help!!

Comment: I see the problem. In 1.8.7 [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select) returned an array. `Array` does not have a method `keys`. Bingo! (The error message may have mentioned the class `array`.) In later versions [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) returns a hash. I'll edit my code to convert the array to a hash.

Comment: Rather than converting the array to a hash, I decided it was better to pull the desired values (keys if were a hash) out of the array directly. That way, it should work with all Ruby versions (since, for a hash `h`, `h.map(&:first)`, `h.to_a.map(&:first)` and `hkeys` all return the same array).

Comment: Hi Cary, Thanks for your help. However, upon running of my test cases, I found that the array that was given has expanded so huge that the counts ranges from 30 - 69. Therefore ` unique_products = counts.select { |_,count| count == 1 }.keys` would not work as I get the results `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Thanks Cary, I've sent you an email, hopefully it  finds you well. Once again, thank you so much.